# Elegant way to count how many pieces of each type are present in a position

Tags: java

I have an abstract class which has 1 attributes like so:

```
PieceColor {
    WHITE, BLACK
}

abstract class Piece {
    PieceColor color

    abstract char getAbbr();
}
```

This class Piece has been extended by the classes Bishop Knight Rook King Queen and Pawn. Each of those class have a method called getAbbr() which returns the abbreviation of the Piece, KQBNRP.

Now I have a `Map<Piece, Tile> piecePlacements` which represents all the pieces currently on the board at a particular time.

I need to count how many pieces are there of a type say White Rook, Black Queen etc. But the normal way of doing this gets too long and is very ugly to look at. This is how I did it...

```
//0: White pieces, 1: Black pieces; 0-5: KQRBNP
    int[][] pieceCount = new int[2][6];

    for(Piece piece : piecePlacements.keySet()) {
        switch (piece.getAbbr()) {
            case 'K' :
                if (piece.color == PieceColor.WHITE) {
                    pieceCount[0][0]++;
                } else {
                    pieceCount[1][0]++;
                }
                break;
            case 'Q' :
                if (piece.color == PieceColor.WHITE) {
                    pieceCount[0][1]++;
                } else {
                    pieceCount[1][1]++;
                }
                break;
            case 'R' :
                if (piece.color == PieceColor.WHITE) {
                    pieceCount[0][2]++;
                } else {
                    pieceCount[1][2]++;
                }
                break;
            case 'B' :
                if (piece.color == PieceColor.WHITE) {
                    pieceCount[0][3]++;
                } else {
                    pieceCount[1][3]++;
                }
                break;
            case 'N' :
                if (piece.color == PieceColor.WHITE) {
                    pieceCount[0][4]++;
                } else {
                    pieceCount[1][4]++;
                }
                break;
            case 'P' :
                if (piece.color == PieceColor.WHITE) {
                    pieceCount[0][5]++;
                } else {
                    pieceCount[1][5]++;
                }
                break;
         }
    }
```

There has to be a more elegant way to this, which takes fewer lines of code. I mean what if there were more than 6 types of pieces and 2 types of colors. I cant just keep adding cases to the switch statement like this right? But I cant figure how to make this more elegant.

Comment: Why aren't enums being used for pieceType and color? Why is a Set being used when duplicates pieces are possible? Why is a 2D array with arbitrary indexing being used rather than a simple Map<Piece, Integer>?

Comment: Why do you need to count the pieces of a chess game? Every chess game starts with 16 peons, 4 rooks, 4 knights, 4 bishops, 2 queens and 2 kings. Just subtract/add when a unit gets destroyed/created.

Comment: To clarify, if you make enumerations for piece type and colour, you can use those as indexes into a `Map` and save your counts there. For that matter, you can still use the type and colour Strings as `Map` indexes to simplify this code, but enums can also be used as `switch` cases.

Comment: @bliss I was just trying to keep things simple, maybe I oversimplified. Sorry about that. I added a few more things with an edit.

Comment: @paladin People might start from a random position with an FEN string in the app I am creating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

Define enums for both color and role of each piece.

Use the misnamed [`Enum#ordinal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal()) to get the index number of each enum object’s position within its definition. Use that number as the index into your arrays.

```java
for ( Piece piece : pieces )          // `Piece` is class with two member fields: a `Color` enum object and a `Role` enum object.
{
    pieceCount                        // Your two-dimensional array. 
        [ piece.color().ordinal() ]   // Get the `Piece` object’s `Color` enum object’s definition position.
        [ piece.role().ordinal() ]    // Get the `Piece` object’s `Role` enum object’s definition position.
        ++                            // Using those two index numbers as index into your arrays, increment the count.
    ;
}
```

## Details

Using enums makes this task much simpler.

Enums offer the method `ordinal`, a misnomer as it actually returns the zero-based index (not one-based ordinal) number of the order in which an enum object was defined. We can use this enum index number as the index into your arrays.

Let's define your `Piece` record with a pair of nested enums, `Color` and `Role`.

A [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) is a new feature in Java 16, for a brief way to write a class whose main purpose is transparently and immutably communicating data. The compiler implicitly creates constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`. Not necessary for this solution, but ideal fit for your `Piece` class.

```java
package work.basil.example.chess;

public record Piece(Color color , Role role)
{
    public enum Color
    { WHITE, BLACK }

    public enum Role
    { KING, QUEEN, ROOK, BISHOP, KNIGHT, PAWN }
}
```

So `Piece.Color.WHITE.ordinal()` returns 0, while `BLACK` returns 1.

We need some sample data.

```java
List < Piece > pieces = List.of(
        new Piece( Piece.Color.BLACK , Piece.Role.QUEEN ) ,
        new Piece( Piece.Color.BLACK , Piece.Role.KNIGHT ) ,
        new Piece( Piece.Color.WHITE , Piece.Role.PAWN )
);
```

We can define your arrays in a soft-coded way, by asking each enum for its length.

```java
int[][] pieceCount = new int[ Piece.Color.values().length ][ Piece.Role.values().length ]; // [2][6]
```

Next we loop the pieces on the board. We ask each `Piece` object’s `Color` and `Role` enum member field object for its index position by calling that misnamed `ordinal()` method.

```java
for ( Piece piece : pieces )
{
    pieceCount[ piece.color().ordinal() ][ piece.role().ordinal() ]++;
}
```

Here is entire example app class.

```java
package work.basil.example.chess;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        List < Piece > pieces = List.of(
                new Piece( Piece.Color.BLACK , Piece.Role.QUEEN ) ,
                new Piece( Piece.Color.BLACK , Piece.Role.KNIGHT ) ,
                new Piece( Piece.Color.WHITE , Piece.Role.PAWN )
        );
        int[][] pieceCount = new int[ Piece.Color.values().length ][ Piece.Role.values().length ]; // [2][6]
        for ( Piece piece : pieces )
        {
            pieceCount[ piece.color().ordinal() ][ piece.role().ordinal() ]++;
        }

        System.out.println( "pieces = " + pieces );
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < pieceCount.length ; i++ )
        {
            System.out.println( Arrays.toString( pieceCount[ i ] ) );
        }
    }
}
```

When run.

```
pieces = [Piece[color=BLACK, role=QUEEN], Piece[color=BLACK, role=KNIGHT], Piece[color=WHITE, role=PAWN]]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Besides being a clever solution to your challenge, using Java enums offers three other big wins:

- Makes your code more [self-documenting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code).
- Provides [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).
- Ensures valid values.

Comment: Yes, looks like the ordinal method is pretty useful here. Only thing is I dont have an enum for role, I just extend the Piece class. If there is no better way then I would definitely define an enum for role and use your approach. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @ChinmayBanerjee Using Java enums makes your code more [self-documenting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code), provides [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety), and ensures valid values — three big wins.

Answer (score 2):

The normal way to do this would be with an [enumerator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) (which is called `enum` in Java).  Enumerators let you define a set of values, and they automatically do all the rest of the work, like assigning a unique ID to each value, under the hood.  Here's a quick example:

```java
public enum PieceType {
    KING,
    QUEEN,
    ROOK,
    BISHOP,
    KNIGHT,
    PAWN;
}
```

And then you could use this in your `Piece` class.  I will also add proper encapsulation, which is something you should follow.

```java
public class Piece {
    private final PieceType type;
    private final boolean isBlack;

    public Piece(PieceType type, boolean isBlack) {
        this.type = type;
        this.isBlack = isBlack;
    }

    public PieceType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public boolean isBlack() {
        return isBlack;
    }
}
```

Now that we have that all set up, it becomes trivial to write your for loop:

```java
for (Piece piece : piecePlacements) {
    pieceCount[piece.isBlack() ? 1 : 0][piece.getType().ordinal()]++;
}
```

For the first dimension's index, we use the [ternary operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).  This allows us to write a conditional expression without writing out a whole if statement.  In this case, if `piece.isBlack()` is true, it plugs in an index of `1`, else, it plugs in an index of `0`.

For the second dimension's index, we use the [`ordinal()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal()) method.  This is a special method that all enumerators implicitly have.  It returns the unique ID for a given enumerator value, and the nice part is, you don't have to worry about how it comes up with that ID.  It does it all automatically.

Comment: Same idea as @Basil Bourque's answer. The only nagging issue I have with this is that I feel creating an enum for piecetypes will be a bit redundant as everytime I extend piece class to add another piece, I have to remember to add it to the enum. But it definitely is a lot more elegant that what I came up with so if I cant find anything better I will use this. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: No problem.  Yeah, one of those annoying situations, we posted within 10 seconds of each other, we were probably working on the exact same answer at the same time.  Oh well.  I'm not sure I follow what you're saying about adding more pieces, though.  Are you saying you'd like to have more types, beyond just the normal 6?  If so you should only have to modify the enum, you shouldn't have to touch your `Piece` class at all.

Comment: Yea, I do have plans of creating unique pieces in the future. So in my project the Piece class is abstract and I extend it for every type of piece I create. Thus once I create a new piece I have to remember to add it to the pieceTypes enum was what I meant in my original comment. But its really no big deal.. this is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting things first can often speed up a count. If you know the order, you can reduce the number of tests.

Another angle is to have a prime number associated with each item. Multiply each into a total. Then divide by that prime to get a count for the corresponding item.

But truly, the right answer will probably involve enums. Also, fewer lines of code doesn't necessarily mean the calculation is done more quickly or efficiently.